# Slicing the output of grep in bash

Tags: bash, grep, array, tail

I'm trying to read a line of text in bash using `grep`, piped to `tail` to get the final line of the file, and then slice the first three "words" (i.e. dividing them using space) of that line as elements of an array.

It works fine if I try to, e.g. loop over the elements in the output using a `for` loop, and I get the list of elements I want:

```
[] foo=$(grep select file.txt | tail -n 1)
[] echo $foo
0.47331 5.11188 13.1615 # select

[] for x in $foo; do echo $x; done
0.47331
5.11188
13.1615
#
select
```

Exactly what I want it to do!

But if I try to get out an array with the first three elements of `foo`, I cannot get it to work:

```
[] echo "${foo[@]:0:2}"
0.47331 5.11188 13.1615 # select 4.95294 13.5177
```

What's particularly weird is that those last two values at the end of the line are actually two values from the *first* line containing `select` in `file.txt` (and not even the first two items on that line, but the second and third!), so they shouldn't even be part of `foo` at all...

Similarly, if I try and simply slice a single "word" from `foo`, I get a weird output:

```
[] echo "${foo[0]}"
0.47331 5.11188 13.1615 # select

[] echo "${foo[1]}"
4.95294
```

(Again, that last value is a value that shouldn't, as I best understand it, even be in `foo`, it's the second item on the first line with `select` in `file.txt`...).

I need to understand what is going on, and how to get out the output I want, namely an array `0.47331 5.11188 13.1615`.

Comment: if you want us to help, please could you provide a simple example of your issue, with input/output/expected output and describe what is not working simply ?

Comment: Does `foo=( $(grep select file.txt | tail -n 1) )` solve all your problems?

Comment: `echo "${foo[@]:0:2}"` ... you haven't created a `foo` array yet, so what did you expect this to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$foo` isn't an array; it's a string containing several space-separated words. If you want it to be an array, assign it as one:

```
foo=( $(grep 'select' file.txt | tail -n 1) )
```

Now you can reference `${foo[0]}`, or the first three elements as `${foo[@]:0:3}`.

Note that `${foo[@]}` will contain all five elements from your last matching line as there's nothing here to extract just the first three elements. You could use `foo=("${foo[@]:0:3}")` to chop `${foo[@]}` down to size if you wanted.

Alternatively, if you want to create the array with just the first three elements you can use `awk` like this:

```
foo=( $(awk '/select/ { a=$1; b=$2; c=$3 } END { print a,b,c }' file.txt) )
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, and I can then use ${foo[@]:0:3} to get the first three elements.
But do you know how the script above is pulling elements that I didn't think would even be in `foo`?

Comment: The array is made from all the space-separated elements. There was nothing in your code to pick out just the first three.

Comment: But given that `foo` was defined as the output of the `grep` piped to `tail`, how does the slicing call get the values that are in `file.txt`?
Or am I wrong, and `foo` actually somehow contains all of the `grep` call, even though the `for` loop doesn't see it?

Comment: Your `$foo` was a string containing the result of your `grep | tail`. It had five space-separated elements. We can force that as an array with the `foo=( ... )` construct, but it still has five elements. You can pick out the first three with `${foo[@]:0:3}`. I've updated my answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 1):

This avoids reading the data into variables:

```
$ grep -F select file | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1-3
0.47331 5.11188 13.1615
```

To get the values into an array in `bash`, use `mapfile` (or `readarray`):

```
$ mapfile -t arr < <( grep -F select file | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1-3 | tr ' ' '\n' )
$ printf 'arr: %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
arr: 0.47331
arr: 5.11188
arr: 13.1615
```

I'm using `tr` to change the spaces between the numbers to newlines.  That way I don't get a trailing newline character at the end of the last value in the array.

---

Instead of the awkward `grep`+`tail`+`cut`+`tr` pipeline, you could obviously use

```
awk '/select/ { a=$1; b=$2; c=$3 } END { printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", a, b, c) }'
```

or something like it inside the `<(...)` process substitution.